# Shardsize, filedimensions, maxpixels, etc to get single raster output to cover state of Colorado?

Tags: google-earth-engine

Can anybody tell me what to specify to get a single raster export to cover the state of Colorado?

I know this would require adjusting shardsize, filedimensions, etc but I do not know how to figure that out. Setting maxpixels to 2e10 seemed to work for one dataset resulting in two outputs with the geoometry set to just outside the state boundaries, one giving me coverage for the whole state and another of just a sliver outside of of the boundary. Working with a different dataset results in 4 outputs. Given that I need to loop this 30+ times I don't want to have to stitch together that many rasters to get what I need.

```js
var cover = ee.ImageCollection("projects/rangeland-analysis-platform/vegetation-cover-v3")

// Author: Eric Jensen and Matt Jones, Working Lands for Wildlife, University of Montana // Contact: eric.jensen@mso.umt.edu // Date: January 1, 2022 // Purpose of script: This script exports RAP Annual Herbaceous Biomass raster data (TIF file format) from Google Earth Engine to your personal Google Drive // Supporting article: https://support.rangelands.app/article/63-export-annual-biomass-rasters

// ------------------------------------------------------------ // -------------- Variables for User to change ---------------- // ------------------------------------------------------------

// ---------- Define the bounding box ------------------------------ // If bounding box was drawn on map below, no additional steps are needed. // // If a shapefile was loaded - rename shapefile to 'geometry'. To do this // click the default shapefile name (likely 'table') in the Imports panel above, // and rename it 'geometry'

// ---------- Define the years that you want to export -------------- // ---------- End year is inclusive in this case ------------------ var yearStart = 1986; var yearEnd = 2022;

// -------------- Define the plant functional types (PFTs) that you want to export -------------- // PFTs are 'afgAGB' (annual forb and grass aboveground biomass), // 'pfgAGB' (perennial forb and grass aboveground biomass), // and 'herbaceousAGB' (total herbaceous aboveground biomass) var PFTs = ee.List(['afgAGB', 'pfgAGB', 'herbaceousAGB']);

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------- // -------------- Do not edit anything below this header ---------------- // ----------------------------------------------------------------------

// -------------- Import and convert annual net primary productivity to aboveground herbaceous biomass production -------------- var npp = ee.ImageCollection("projects/rangeland-analysis-platform/npp-partitioned-v3") .select(['afgNPP', 'pfgNPP']); var mat = ee.ImageCollection("projects/rangeland-analysis-platform/gridmet-MAT");

// biomass conversion function // input: two band image (afgNPP, pfgNPP) from projects/rangeland-analysis-platform/npp-partitioned-v2 // output: three band image, aboveground biomass (afgAGB, pfgAGB, herbaceousAGB) var biomassFunction = function(image) {

var year = ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start')).format('YYYY');
var matYear = mat.filterDate(year).first();
var fANPP = (matYear.multiply(0.0129)).add(0.171).rename('fANPP'); // fraction of NPP to allocate aboveground

var agb = image.multiply(0.0001) // NPP scalar 
            .multiply(2.20462) // KgC to lbsC
            .multiply(4046.86) // m2 to acres
            .multiply(fANPP)  // fraction of NPP aboveground
            .multiply(2.1276) // C to biomass
            .rename(['afgAGB', 'pfgAGB'])
            .copyProperties(image, ['system:time_start'])
            .set('year', year);

var herbaceous = ee.Image(agb).reduce(ee.Reducer.sum()).rename(['herbaceousAGB']);

agb = ee.Image(agb).addBands(herbaceous);

return agb;
};

var biomass = npp.map(biomassFunction);

// ------------- Select the PFTs for export as defined by User -------------- var biomass_toExport = biomass.select(PFTs).filterBounds(geometry);

// ------------- Export images one-by-one for each year -------------

// Edit the folder in your drive for exporting ////

// Loop over year objects to export images year-by-year for (var yr = yearStart; yr <= yearEnd; yr++){ // Export the image, specifying scale and region. Export.image.toDrive({ image: biomass_toExport.filterDate(yr.toString(), (yr+1).toString()).first(), description: 'RAP_Biomass_stackCO' + yr, /// This is the file name, which will automatically have the year appended to it folder: 'rap', /// This needs to be a folder within your Google Drive. This is where the file will go scale: 30, region: geometry, // The geometry is used a few times in this script. It's the bounding box for CO, but you can change that in the header at the top of the script maxPixels: 10e10 }); }
```